# Get Background Color from HTML

Tags: itext

While converting HTML to PDF, I am not getting background color applied for the text where as fore color working fine. When I debug, I found that Chunk object does not have that background color which is taken from HTML that contains background color.

Is there any way that I can find chunk background color, so that I can set it by using `SetBackground` method? I am using HTMLWorker.ParseToList Method and adding elements with customized formatting in pdf but want to get font background color from HTML.

Comment: I should probably downvote the question because you're not specifying if you're using HTMLWorker (which is deprecated) or XML Worker (which is what you should do). Without that info, nobody can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

sorry not possible. Even I faced this problem